# PrimeSense Carmine not working under Groovy but works in Fuerte

Tags: ros, openni, primesense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a PrimeSense Carmine sensor (1.09), it works before under both Groovy and Fuerte following the workaround provied by [PrimeSense Carmine doesn't work, but ASUS Xtion does](http://answers.ros.org/question/54747/primesense-carmine-doesnt-work-but-asus-xtion-does-openni-launch-devices-connected-but-not-found/?answer=54760#post-id-54760). But after several updates, the openni_launch in Groovy no longer works, while the Fuerte one still do. I did the following experiments to investigate the error:

== under ROS Groovy and Fuerte, original package WITHOUT Sensor-Bin-Linux-x86-v5.1.2.1 ==

Driver won't start with openni.launch, giving such error:

```
[ INFO] [1385557309.784984535]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

== under ROS Groovy, after installing Sensor-Bin-Linux-x86-v5.1.2.1 ==

openni.launch will crash, giving many errors, only sensable ones are listed here:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-openni-camera-1.8.9-0precise-20131016-0128/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

           Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.2.1: Failed to set USB interface!

           [FATAL] [1385557181.994270107]: Service call failed!
```

== under ROS Fuerte, after installing Sensor-Bin-Linux-x86-v5.1.2.1, it works smoothly(like the Kinect!) ==

Since we have many other modules work only in ROS Groovy, so we have to make the camera driver working under the same distribution. We are running all these under a 32-bit ubuntu 12.04 machine.

#### update

I checked the ros-groovy-openni-camera package versions, the current version(20131016) does not work. And I cannot install the old version:

`apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-camera=1.8.8-0precise-20130326-0820-+0000`

E: Version '1.8.8-0precise-20130326-0820-+0000' for 'ros-groovy-openni-camera' was not found

```
1.8.8-0precise-20130326-0820-+0000
# this seems to be the start point when it failed
1.8.9-0precise-20130715-0342-+0000
1.8.9-0precise-20130722-0045-+0000
1.8.9-0precise-20130724-2247-+0000
1.8.9-0precise-20130926-0224-+0000
1.8.9-0precise-20131016-0128-+0000
```

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105296/primesense-carmine-not-working-under-groovy-but-works-in-fuerte/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Already have an issue here, https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_camera/issues/18

---

Originally posted by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) with karma: 391 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-11-27**:
Did you try to check out the source code and compile it yourself? Try using the 1.8.8 or rollback_usb branch.

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2013-11-27**:
I have a solution here: http://answers.ros.org/question/70585/roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-no-devices-connected. I'm using 12.10 with groovy, but you can try and see if it works.

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2013-12-06**:
Thanks @Andrew.A ! I followed your guide to download the source and compile it on the rollback_usb branch, now it works.